# Cookie not deleting from Chrome 84.0.4147.105 (Official Build) (64-bit) in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, cookies

I have problem deleting/updating cookie from asp.net C# side. Its working fine on older version but not on windows chrome 84.0.4147.105

Code to delete cookie

```
 HttpCookie Cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
            if (Cookie != null)
            {
                Cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(Cookie);
            }
```

I have tried adding cookie.secure - true, since this is .net framework version 4.5 i dont have samesite option available in framework or in web.config

Tried IIS rewrite rule and its working. Cookie is both secure and samesite None but still the chromeis not deleting the cookie.

```
<rule name="SessionCookieAddNoneHeader">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern="(.*ACUsername.*)" />
          <!-- Use this regex if your OS/framework/app adds SameSite=Lax automatically to the end of the cookie -->
          <!-- <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern="((.*)(ASP.NET_SessionId)(=.*))(?=SameSite)" /> -->
          <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}; SameSite=None" />
        </rule>
```

Please help if someone is facing the same issue with newer chrome version

Thanks

Comment: Oh my god! I have been going crazy over this....after 4-5 hours of debugging, I believe this is the issue in this version but one of my colleague has the same version of chrome but cookie is being deleted just fine. The only solution/hack that I am able to figure out is to delete the cookies using JavaScript on the client side.

My site/code works perfectly fine on older versions and other browsers.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1112297

Comment: Thanks, @NewbieProgrammer. Seems like its Windows 10 chrome that is affected. I am upgrading my app version to 4.7.2 to support **sameSite** attribute in web.config for httpCookies
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite#using-samesite-in-aspnet-472-and-48
For a workaround i am using IIS rewrite rule but still have to mention cookie.Secure = true while deleting in C#

Answer (score 0):

We also faced the same issue and noticed that it was deleting an older version, so to delete the cookie from latest version we did following -

```
HttpCookie Cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
if (Cookie != null)
{
    Cookie.Secure = true;
    Cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(Cookie);
}
```

And while adding cookie, we added

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["cookie"].SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
```

The following backward-compatible behaviors are removed as of Chrome 80:

> Disallow defaulting of SameSite attribute to ‘None’: The SameSite
> attribute now defaults to Lax, meaning your cookies are only available
> to other sites from top-level navigations. As originally implemented
> in Chrome, the SameSite attribute defaults to None, which was
> essentially the Web’s status quo. Cookies have valid cross-site use
> cases, but if a site owner did not previously want to allow cross-site
> cookie use, there was no way to declare such an intent or enforce it.
> Value ‘None’ no longer allowed on insecure contexts: Chrome now
> requires that when the SameSite attribute is set to None, the Secure
> attribute must also be present. The Secure attribute requires that the
> attached cookie can only be transmitted over a secure protocol such as
> HTTPS.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2)` to expire a cookie because your visitors might have a computer-clock set incorrectly (2 days is too close for comfort - I'm guilty of it myself: I once had the correct day and month but the wrong year). Why aren't you using the officially recommended value of `1970-01-01 00:00:00Z` (UTC) - which is also `0` in UNIX timekeeping units - as that will always be expired (provided that the `SameSite` property is correct, of course)

Comment: thanks Dai, I was not aware of this one, will update my answer then.